# symfony2 service array parameters. How to get value based on key

Tags: php, symfony, service

I'm creating new invoice form, which includes select input with some constant values.
I've made it through services:

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
    stawki_vat:
        0: 0%
        5: 5%
        8: 8%
        23: 23%
        zw: zw.
services:
    acme.form.type.stawki_vat:
        class: Acme\FakturyBundle\Form\Type\StawkiVatType
        arguments:
            - "%stawki_vat%"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: stawki_vat }
```

**StawkiVatType.php**

```
class StawkiVatType extends AbstractType
{
    private $stawkiVatChoices;

    public function __construct(array $stawkiVatChoices) {
        $this->stawkiVatChoices = $stawkiVatChoices;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => $this->stawkiVatChoices,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'stawki_vat';
    }
}
```

**TowarType.php**

```
class TowarType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nazwa_towar', null, array('label' => 'Nazwa towaru/usługi'))
        ->add('cena_netto', null, array(
            'label' => 'Cena netto'
        ))
        ->add('vat', 'stawki_vat', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'styled'),
            'label' => 'Stawka VAT',
        ))
    ;
}
```

In form, everything works perfect.
But now, I want to get a value stored in database (key of stawki_vat) and show a value of stawki_vat array.

How to achieve this in simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your entity manager to your custom form type service. Presuming you are using Doctrine:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    acme.form.type.stawki_vat:
        class: Acme\FakturyBundle\Form\Type\StawkiVatType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","%stawki_vat%"]
```

**StawkiVatType.php**

```
class StawkiVatType extends AbstractType
{
private $stawkiVatChoices;
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, array $stawkiVatChoices) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->stawkiVatChoices = $stawkiVatChoices;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you ever need to inject a service which you know exists, but you do not know the name of, you can use `php app/console container:debug`. For instance, `php app/console container:debug | grep EntityManager` will output `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager container Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` which shows the name of the service (`doctrine.orm.entity_manager` is simply an alias for this service).

Comment: Ok, in form it works good, but how to display i.e. '23%' instead of '23' in list of invoices? How to get stawki_vat properties and display value for this specific key?

Comment: You need to [create a template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field) for your custom form type.